# Openui5 mobile devices splitapp menu button is not visible

Tags: android, sapui5

I have developed the splitapp application and it's working fine in desktop and tablet but in mobile devices splitapp menu button is not visible and master page fully covered.

[image: web view]

[image: mobile view]

Comment: What do you refer as 'split app menu button' ??? +you put twice the same image

Comment: sorry ash kander some confusion.. now i am updated done.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as designed. The reason for this is readability on small and narrow screens.

In the docu [here](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/split-screen/) it says:
“On narrow screens for phones (or tablet devices in portrait mode), the master list and the details are split into two separate pages.
The user navigates between the list and details, and can see all the available information for each.”

Comment: So side menu is not coming for mobile device

Comment: Side menu should come up, if you touch on the “Greater”-signs in “Attachment”, “Notes” and “People”. But at the same time it’s either one or the other on phones, as mentioned in the docu. Only on larger screens, you will see both at the same time.

Comment: I’m sorry, but maybe I misunderstood your question.
When you say “side menu”, are you referring to the “Detail”-screen of the splitapp with the round buttons “Attachment”, “Notes” and “People” as seen in your screenshot ?
The question for a “Burger Menu” might be different from this.
You might want to look at [this example here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListToolbar/preview),
where you can see 3 headerToolbar-buttons at the top right for settings, people and drop-down-list.
At the very top you can also switch to the corresponding UI5 coding.

Answer (score 0):

Api reference clearly says the responsive behaviour in small screens
[openui5 api reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SplitApp)

If you are looking for android drawer like menu with html see
[side nav with html](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp)

Comment: so side menu not avaiable in openui5. if we want we use it javascript nav right

Comment: side menu not available...Not in sapui5 also.